# Twitter-Bootstrap, image cover - fitting all avaiable space

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm aware that there's some answers already, but I didn't find them useful.

Please visit http://mosek.pl/v2

I want to have this background fitting all the screen, but also keep this parallax effect. 
Is it possible with some minor changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code

**CSS**

```
#intro{
  min-height:100vh;
}
```

Comment: But since I changed to your solution, if I will load this website n a mobile, height of screen takes more than 100% of avaiable height, takes around 120%. Do You have comment on that?